# Using an e-mail service anonymously

Tags: privacy, email

What are the options, to use an e-mail service anonymously without exposing yourself (your private info, name etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

Bitmessage is a decentralized, encrypted, peer-to-peer, trustless communications protocol that can be used by one person to send encrypted messages to another person, or to multiple subscribers.

so using this you can use [bitmessage](https://bitmessage.ch/) email service anonymously

and here is the guide to use it
[guide to setup bitmessage](http://www.guidingtech.com/25538/using-bitmessage-online/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list for [privacy conscious e-mail services](http://prxbx.com/email/).

I personally use [Autistici/Inventati](http://www.autistici.org/en/services/mail.html) and they don't want any information about you when you sign up for an e-mail address.

> ... we won't ask you your fiscal code, neither a document number or your name and surname to activate your mailbox.

They won't log your IP addresses either.

Answer (score 0):

You can to what [Satoshi Nakamoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto) did, and simply use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) (or [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)) create an email account with any free email service (that does not require SMS validation or validation through a pre-existing email address).  Just be sure to use TOR/Tails when you create the account, and every time you access it.

Answer (score 0):

For protecting your personal data as a new user of a service use Tor/Tails.

For protecting message content and confidentiality use GPG.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Protonmail, its encrypted end to end and doesnt ask for a name when signing up. just a username and password, it does ask for a backup email address but from what i have seen its pretty good.

Comment: How can it be anonymous if it asks for an email

Comment: its optional. you can always link another email that has no connection to you. no one said it has to be one with your name on it